# Корректный принт в файл русских символов python 2

Tags: python, кодировка, python-2.x

Имеется небольшая программа на Python 2, которая проходит по одному файлу с русскими словами и добавляет их в коллекцию, потом эта коллекция записывается в json файл

```
f = open("in.txt")
conversations = open("data/russian/conversations.json", "wb")
ar = {"conversations": []}

worker = []
for line in f:
    if line == "-----":
        ar["conversations"].append(worker)
        worker = []
    else:
        worker.append(line)
print ar["conversations"][0][0]
conversations.write(str(ar))
conversations.close()
```

В итоге в json файле я имею что-то подобное:

> {'conversations': [['\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82!', '\xd0\x97\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd1\x83\xd0\xb9!', // и так далее

Вопрос заключается в следующем: как корректно выводить русские символы в файл? (.encode("utf-8") пытался, не помогло)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка у вас в том, что *`str(ar)` это неправильный способ сохранить словарь как json*. Tо что вы видите это текстовое представление байтовых строк в Питоне—ожидаемый результат при вызове `str()` на коллекцию—подобное однозначное представление полезно для отладки.

Используйте json модуль вместо этого: `json.dump(ar, file)`.

Но и этого не достаточно в вашем случае: json это текстовый формат, а у вас код с байтами работает. Используйте `io.open(filename, mode, encoding=character_encoding)`, чтобы читать/писать текст, а не байты из файла.

Также можно `from __future__ import unicode_literals` добавить наверху, чтобы руками `u''` префикс перед каждой строковой константой не писать.