# по кодировкам utf-8 выдает результат по-разному при печати строк по отдельности и списка целиком

Tags: python, utf-8, unicode

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в нижеприведенном коде результаты внутри цикла возвращаются кириллицей, а за циклом уже в другой кодировке?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
path_f = []
for d, dirs, files in os.walk(u'd:\удалить'):
    for f in files:
        path = os.path.join(d,f)
        path_f.append(path)
        print(path)
print(path_f)`
```

результат

```
d:\удалить\реестр1.xlsx  
d:\удалить\реестр2.xlsx

[u'd:\\\u0443\u0434\u0430\u043b\u0438\u0442\u044c\\\u0440\u0435\u0435\u0441\u0442\u04401.xlsx',      u'd:\\\u0443\u0434\u0430\u043b\u0438\u0442\u044c\\\u0440\u0435\u0435\u0441\u0442\u04402.xlsx']
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python. Перевести байт-код в человекочитаемый вид в элементе списка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/521481/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python string prints as `[u'String']`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/599625/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599625/python-string-prints-as-ustring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что path - строка и выводится как строка, а path_f - список, при попытке распечатать его происходит сериализация и на вывод попадает "как бы бинарная" форма. Если хотите вывести весь список как набор строк, нужно сделать явное его преобразование в строку. Например вот так:

```
print('[%s]' % ','.join(path_f))
```

В этом случае вывод будет такой же, как у Вас (как бы дамп списка), но строки будут читаемыми.

Comment: а если я хочу записать результат в файл? почему при str(('[%s]' % ','.join(path_f)))) выдается 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-8: ordinal not in range(128)?

Comment: *«"как бы бинарная" форма»*--для ясности это не бинарная форма--это текстовое представление списка (как его можно было бы в исходном коде задать в виде константы).

Comment: @Александр Кудрявцев, а вот тут мы утыкаемся сразу в две проблемы.Проблема номер раз: видимо, Вы используете старую версию интерпретатора, а все 2.x уже довольно давно старые. Если Вы работаете с новым проектом, используйте третью ветку. Вторая - чисто для поддержки уже написанных и работающих.

Comment: @АлександрКудрявцев потому что не следует вызывать `str(u'ф')` ни на какой версии Питона (либо ошибка, либо не нужно). Если не знаете как сохранить unicode в файл, задайте отдельный вопрос. См. [Корректный принт в файл русских символов python 2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527540/23044). Прочтите [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538619/23044)